# Is it possible to run UI Automation as a Windows service?

Tags: windows, appium, winappdriver

I have a Windows VM with a desktop application on it. I want to write an agent which will interact with this application through UI automation (via [WinAppDriver](https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver)). The agent should start with the machine and require as little human intervention as possible to do its job.

It's easy enough to get this working by adding it to startup programs (shell:startup), but this requires someone logging into the VM every time it is restarted. Is it possible to run such a program as a Windows Service? Keep in mind it would have to launch a Win32 app and interact with it via UI automation. Could this be done by running it as Local System account and enabling "Allow service to interact with desktop"? Or would it need to run as a specific user account?

Comment: Bear in mind that you can't run arbitrary applications on the secure desktop shown before someone has logged in. You need to solve the "have a user log in to windows" problem before you can launch your arbitrary program and once you've solved that, shell:startup will already work.

Comment: Would this limitation also apply to exes launched via Task Scheduler? You couldn't launch a GUI app until someone had logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is because Windows Service runs in background and to access the UI the process should run foreground.

Comment: Then... How services like RDP and VNC do work?